# custom view cannot be instantiated in xml layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view, glsurfaceview

I have a class like this :

```
public class MyOpenGlView extends GLSurfaceView
    {

        public MyOpenGlView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setRenderer(new MyRenderer()) ;
        }
    }
```

and I want to declare this class in my xml layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OpenGlActivity" >

    <test.example.myfirstapp.OpenGlActivity.MyOpenGlView android:id = "@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

but then there is this error in "Graphical Layout" mode :

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- test.example.myfirstapp.OpenGlActivity.MyOpenGlView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse
```

what's the problem?

Comment: are you sure you put the exact package?

Comment: yes,

the package is : test.example.myfirstapp , 

the activity is : OpenGlActivity , 

the class is : MyOpenGlView ,

Answer (score 1):

Try putting  setRenderer(new MyRenderer()) ; under isInEditMode() like

```
if (isInEditMode())
{
 setRenderer(new MyRenderer()) ;
}
```

Also in your XML File try changing

```
<test.example.myfirstapp.OpenGlActivity.MyOpenGlView android:id = "@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    />
```

to

```
 <MyOpenGlView android:id = "@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    />
```

if you are using android studio and let it import the class automatically

else try changing it to

```
<view
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="test.example.myfirstapp.OpenGlActivity.MyOpenGlView"
    android:id="@+id/myImage" />
```